# React Native + Redux: Why the error "should not push route with duplicated key"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

I have Redux set up for my React Native project. The following is my navigation reducer (`navReducer.js`):

```
import { PUSH_ROUTE, POP_ROUTE } from '../Constants/ActionTypes'
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'

import Login from '../Components/Login'

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental

const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

And in my root component (`NavRoot.js`), the actions are handled with:

```
  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }
```

And triggered by the button (`NavButton.js`):

```
  _navigate(route){
    this.props._handleNavigate(route)
  }

  render(){
    const route = {
      type: 'push',
      route: {
        key: this.props.navKey,
        title: this.props.pageName,
        component: this.props.componentName
      }
    }

    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._navigate(route)}>
        <Text style={styles}>{pr.pageName}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
```

When the button (`NavButton.js`) is pressed for the first time, it navigates correctly. But when it is pressed again, I get the following error: `should not push route with duplicated key /*'route.key: this.props.navKey' in this case*/`.

All seemed to makes sense, but what may be the issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> should not push route with duplicated key

The `key` property must be unique.

If you need to create the several scenes with the same `key`, you can pass to the reducer something like `scene` property and increment the `key` value...

```
function navigation(state = guestState, action) {
  const { index, routes } = state

  switch (action.type) {
    case NAV_PUSH: {
      const nextIndex = index + 1
      const newState = {
        ...action.state,
        key: `${action.state.scene}_${nextIndex}`,
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        index: nextIndex,
        routes: [
          ...routes,
          newState,
        ],
      }
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but could you show an example with the code I provided, with `NavigationStateUtils`? Can't seem to wrap around how it would work with my code.

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your input is coming consecutively within your navigation reducer:

```
case 'PUSH_ROUTE':
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
      if ((state.routes.length && state.routes[state.routes.length-1].key) === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)
```